# Как в c# сделать обновление информации в активном времени?

Tags: c#

То есть например в файле .txt изменил значение и оно моментально обновилось в программе.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Стандартный для этого способ в c# - [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) с нужным фильтром.

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = path;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

И где-то поместите обработчик ваших изменений:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  //
}
```

Примеров в сети про FileSystemWatcher много и на русском ([пример](http://netobf.com/Examples_FileSystemWatcher)) и на английском ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017506/using-filesystemwatcher-to-monitor-a-directory)), можете копнуть глубже тему.